# How to encode an audio file to bytes in UTF-8 in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, encoding, google-api, character-encoding

I am trying to send an audio file that was created with MediaRecorder to the Google Speech To Text API.
The audio file was created by the MediaRecorder with the following rules:

```
protected void setupMediaRecorder() {
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mPathSave);
}
```

after the file is created, I'm doing the following:

```
private void isCorrectAnswer(MediaRecorder iRecorder, final Button iButton)  {
        String url = MYURL;
        File file = new File(mPathSave);
        InputStream inFile = null;
        try {
            inFile = new FileInputStream(mPathSave);
            byte[] bytes = fileToBytes();
            String stringBytes = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            writeToFile(stringBytes, PictureRecognitionLevel.this);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                jsonBody.put("original_text", mQuestion.GetmAnswer());
                jsonBody.put("email", MYMAIL);
                jsonBody.put("audio_file", stringBytes);
                final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
                final JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                iButton.setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        },  new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.print("ERROR!");
                    }
                });
                queue.add(jsonRequest);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


private byte[] fileToBytes() {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    File audioFile = new File(mPathSave);
    try {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

            bytes = Files.readAllBytes(audioFile.toPath());

        } else {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

What I get from this conversion is:

```
#!AMR-WB
 "�����-X���G���HB��@PITCH�@D ����a=)˂����p� c �� ��S(@@UQV�ep�*{�
```

(It's longer than that...)
I've read that the black diamond is a sign for either a problem with reading the data or a problem with the utf-8 encoding.
What can I do to get the file encoded in UTF-8? What am I doing wrong?